# Are Standard Field History Tracking deployable through SFDX?

Tags: field-history, standard-field

My Standard field (Account) on a Standard object (Asset) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>AccountId</fullName>
    <trackHistory>true</trackHistory>
    <type>Lookup</type>
</CustomField>
```

When we deploy the field through SFDX we see track history information is not deployed in target org, i.e. in target org trackHistory is false.

This issue doesn't happen with Custom fields.

I remember about 8 years back this was an issue while migrating with Eclipse. Is it still an issue?

If so, any relevant links would be highly appreciated, as I could find none.

Comment: Just tried it on a developer org in API version 49, using `sfdx force:source:deploy` on same AccountId field on Asset, field history tracking deployed successfully. on which API version are you running this? is it sfdx deploy or push command ?

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue with EmailBouncedDate on Leads while deploying via ANT API 53. I found a known issue that looks to be related: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Hlj3QAC